# Задача с BigInt в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, веб-программирование, длинная-арифметика

Всем привет ребята)Зависаю я на CodeWars и попалась тут такая [задача.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a906c895084d7ed740000c2/train/javascript)

Задачу решил и у меня все работает и выдает правильный [результат](https://playcode.io/914439)

Только компилятор CodeWars выдает мне такой Error:
TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions

До этого раньше никогда не работал с BigInt.Может кто хелпануть?

Comment: Ваше решение и задачу нужно публиковать прямо в Stackoverflow (в вопросе), так нужно делать по правилам, а также чисто из-за удобства, к тому же если задача или ваш ответ будет не доступен в CodeWars, то тогда можно будет найти его на Stackoverflow.

Comment: Судя по ошибке вы смешиваете число BigInt с каким-то другим типом данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто надо не смешивать переменные одного типа с числами другого — добавляйте префикс `n` к числам (см. мои `1n` в коде ниже).

Но зачем такое страшное решение? По-моему, вот так гораздо проще:

```
function solve(n) 
{
    let r = 1n, v = 1n;
    for(let i = 1n; i <= n; i++)
    {
        r *= i;
        v *= i+n;
    }
    return v/r/(n+1n);
}
```